# how to find a $f(x)$ equal the given series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

look at this series:

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\dfrac{{{{( - 1)}^{n - 1}}}}
{{2n - 1}}{x^{2n}}}$$

by Cauchy-Hadamard formula,the above series convergence region is $(-1,1)$. at the end points, it is a alternating series. so convergence.so its convergence region is $[-1,1]$.

my question is: how to find a function which Taylor expansion equal the above series?

thanks very much

Comment: Easier to take $\sum \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}x^{2n-1}$ and take the derivative, which is easily summed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\dfrac{{{{( - 1)}^{n - 1}}}}
{{2n - 1}}{x^{2n}}}=x\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\dfrac{{{{( - 1)}^{n - 1}}}}
{{2n - 1}}{x^{2n-1}}} \overset{def}{=}xg(x).$$
Then
$$g'(x)=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{( - 1)}^{n - 1}
{x^{2n-2}}}=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{( - 1)}^{n - 1}
{(x^2)^{n-1}}}=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{( - x^2)}^{n - 1}}=\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{( - x^2)}^{k}}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

For every $x \in [-1,1]$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)
&=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}x^{2n}
=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n} {2n+1}x^{2n+1}=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^xt^{2n}\,dt\\
&=&x\int_0^x\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nt^{2n}\,dt=x\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt
=x\arctan x.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The series
$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\dfrac{{{{( - 1)}^{n}}}}
{{2n + 1}}{x^{2n+1}}}$$
is the Taylor series of $\arctan x$ and converges for $\left|x\right|\le1$.